# Is there a way to create a CFData object from a file using memory-mapped file access?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-foundation

I am restricted to using CoreFoundation in a particular app, and don't have access to `NSData`.

I need to access data from a file using memory mapping because the file could be quite large. With `NSData`, I can achieve this using the `+dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` method, passing in the `NSDataReadingMappedAlways` option.

Is it possible to do this with `CFData`? The only function I can find to actually create a `CFData` object directly from a file is the `CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource()` function, which does not have any option to set the memory mapping flag.

Is there a lower-level way to load a `CFData` object from a file using memory-mapped reads? Do I have to drop down to `mmap` or something?

Comment: As a quick side note: If all you want is to avoid the cache, you should be using NSDataReadingUncached, not NSDataReadingMappedAlways. Unless you actually _need_ the data to be mapped even if unsafe or slower (think NFS), why ask for it? But, more importantly, `NSDataReadingMappedAlways` is just a "Hint to map the file if possible"—and if it can't be mapped, it'll be read normally, and probably stored in the cache.

Comment: Interesting, thanks very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `CFData()` from a byte buffer and a count. Given this, you should just be able to `mmap()` the file in question, and then pass the mapped byte buffer over to `CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy()`. The only real complication is you'll need to use a `CFAllocatorRef` that knows how to `munmap()` as the `bytesDeallocator`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought might be the case. It's a bit annoying that there's no higher-level way to do this but I can work with it.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but it's too long to fit in a comment, so…

In general, when you don't know how to do something from Cocoa/Foundation, it's often worth looking at how the GNUstep equivalent is implemented. Of course GNUstep doesn't implement 100% of the latest version of Foundation, and it's written directly on top of POSIX rather than CoreFoundation, so it isn't always helpful… but often it is.

In [NSData.m](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/gnustep/libs/base/trunk/Source/NSData.m), there's no `+dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`, but there is a `+dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:` (and of course `-initWithContentsOfMappedFile:`) method, and the implementation of the `NSDataMappedFile` class that it depends on.

Ultimately, the `NSDataMappedFile` is a pretty simple wrapper around an `mmap`, and the `NSData` methods just create an `NSDataMappedFile` and call its `-initWithContentsOfMappedFile:`. The only real complexity is the fallback code (which makes sure to fake the mmap and just call `[NSData initWithContentsOfFile:]`)—code which you explicitly don't want.

So, that's a good clue that you want to implement this exactly the way Kevin Ballard suggested.